# Looking for a pin-compatible to LT1013DID rail-to-rail in/out op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, footprint, pinout, replacement

I have designed a circuit using LT1013DID (SOIC 8 footprint) op-amp and while Spice simulation worked, I forgot about input common-mode voltage limit (which it seems is not simulated) and thus need an in/out rail to rail op-amp which LT1013DID isn't (it is out rail-to-rail only) as my real-life circuit/PCB does not work near power supply voltages.

LT1013DID has a specific footprint where pin 1 is A-IN and not A-OUT.

[image: LT1013DID footprint]

I am wondering if anyone is aware of any other op-amps with such footprint layout that I could use as a replacement?

So requirements are: 2 channel SOIC 8 in/out rail-to-rail op-amp with a single supply of more than ~17V that is pin-compatible with LT1013DID

Comment: The input voltage range can be as low as the negative (or 0 volt) rail so maybe consider lifting the positive rail by a couple of volts?

Comment: Unfortunately, the PCB is already manufactured and I can't do changes to it. Therefore I am looking for an alternative if there is any (due to unfortunate choice of op-amp footprint).

Comment: What about a small solderable-to-the-existing-pads daughter board with a different chip. It's a pretty obscure layout for the LT1013.

Comment: This will have to do in case no replacement is found, I am afraid.

Comment: I would start to go down that path and it needn't be bodgy or regarded as a bad solution.